# Script stuck during read line when script is executed remotely

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-server

I want to have one script which starts a services in another server.

I have tested that the script works as expected in the server where the server is going to run.

This is the code which starts the service and monitors the log until it is in the startup process:

```
   pkill -f "$1"
   nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE $1 &

   tail -n 0 -f nohup.out | while read LOGLINE
   do
       echo $LOGLINE
       [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"$L_LOG_STRING"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
   done
```

This works fine as long as I execute that from that machine.

Now I want to call that script from another server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DESTINATION_SERVER=$1
ssh root@$DESTINATION_SERVER /bin/bash << EOF
    echo "Restarting first service..."
    /usr/local/starter.sh -s parameter

    echo "Restarting second service..."
    /usr/local/starter.sh -s parameter2
EOF
```

Well, everytime I try that the script of the remote server gets stuck in the "while READ" loop. But as I said, when I execute it locally from the server works fine, and in my "not simplified script" I´m not using any system variable or similar.

**Update**: I just tried to simplify the code even more with the following lines in the first scenario:

```
pkill -f "$1"
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE $1 &
tail -n 0 -f nohup.out | sed "/$L_LOG_STRING/ q"
```

I'd say the problem is some how in the "|" through ssh, but I still can find why.

Comment: Try putting proper shebangs and adding `PATH` at the top to include paths to all commands used... `java`, `pkill`, `nohup`... You have also written `stater.sh` instead of `starter.sh` presumably. You are also using `bash` features so it is misleading to use the `.sh` extension, IMHO.

Comment: what makes you think a script is getting stuck in a while loop? and which one do you think is getting stuck?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I´ve tried all combinations of "#!/usr/bin/env bash" and "#!/usr/bin/bash" without success. The stater, and starter was just a typo when reducing my problem to ask the question and changing to generic names.

Comment: @jhnc I've been extensively testing what is going on, and the problem is that the pkill command is not being executed when I execute the script remotely, so the script waits for ever, even though the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Maybe the remote server is an OS where `bash` is actually `ash`... https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/143968-differences-bash-ash-shells-regarding-if-command.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell it is a stock debian 9.5 system

Comment: So the second script never runs? and the tail is still running even after the echo shows that the condition is met?

Comment: @jhnc I just checked, actually I had that code from another stackoverflow question, but it seems that it never checks the condition inside the "while do done", it justs starts the tail.

But when runned locally it works as expected

Comment: You do realise you need to `ssh` into the remote server **as root** to test it because the root user will not necessarily have the same PATH as yourself or have `$PROFILE` defined the same as your user...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes I'm login to the server with root, it is stated in "root@$DESTINATION_SERVER". Also $PROFILE was declared before in the script as a property, like "PROFILE=test"

Comment: you gave an updated script but you don't say what happens when you run it. If you replace the tail/sed line with `ls -l nohup.out` what happens?

Comment: Yes, I can see you run your script via `ssh` as root, but I meant that you should run `ssh root@$DESTINATION_SERVER` to login and then, at the prompt, run `/usr/local/starter.sh -s parameter` as a proper test.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell. I just tried. When I log into the server directly from my laptop to the SERVER1(Where the script is located) it works. When I log in to the SERVER2 and then from there to the SERVER1 the script gets stucked in "nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'". So the problem seems to be there and not in the tail.

Comment: Is the `pkill` actually killing a previous process that was also writing to `nohup.out`? If so, you may need a delay after the `pkill` for the previous writer to release write access to the file.

Comment: I just tried putting some sleeps but I was getting the same result. As you mention that with nohup,out I was wondering if the problem was that it was not sending the output to that but some other output. I just change the nohup line to"nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test &1  >> nohup.out &" and it seems to be working. I can´t believe it after so many hours with this issue

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the problem comes from not having an interactive console when you execute the ssh command, therefore the nohup command behaves strangly.

I could solve it in two ways, outputing the code to the file explicitly:

```
"nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test &1 >> nohup.out &"
```

instead of:

```
"nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test &1&"
```

Or changing the way I access via ssh adding the tt option (just one did not work):

```
ssh -tt root@$DESTINATION_SERVER /bin/bash << EOF
```

But this last solution could lead to other problems with some character, so unless someone suggests another solution that is my patch which makes it work.